Alternative to R-squared when calculating glm model using survey package
I'm writing my master thesis using the European Social Survey. The data requires weighting, so therefore I have to use the survey package and its svyglm-function for my regression analysis instead of normal lm (I'm working with R/RStudio). The regression itself works fine, however svyglm does not give any value for R-squared. So what is the best workaround here?
I read about pseudo R-squared (thats also what ChatGPT suggested lol), but I think it's based on maximum likelihood. However, when trying to calculate Nagelkerkes R-squared, RStudio gave me a warning message, that my svyglm object was NOT calculated with maximum likelihood. I didn't specify any non-gaussian family argument in the regression call, because I want to calculate a linear model and that is what the documentation suggested here
I nevertheless got a value, but it differed greatly from the value in the lm model without weighting: Without weight and sampling design, R-squared was 0.03, the calculated Nagelkerkes R-squared from the svyglm model was 0.79. Even if weighting changes the value, with such a huge difference there must be something wrong here.
What method would you suggest here? Should I stick to Pseudo R-squared and if yes, which one? Or should I just try to extract residual sum of squares and total sum of squares to calculate standard R-squared manually?
Thanks for your advice!
PS: For those, who say that I should just skip it: In a previous paper, my lecturer criticized me for not reporting R-squared when working with survey package. So I have to find a way.

Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/73956738/190277 yet?

There are a few possible approaches, depending on what you want to accomplish.
If you just want the grader/reviewer to get off your back, then adherence to any kind of statistical rigor is tangential to your goal. It all comes down to understanding what the reviewer wants, whether the reviewer should want it or not. If the reviewer wants you to calculate the squared Pearson correlation between the observed and predicted values, your options seem to be either to do this calculation or to argue. If the reviewer wants you to submit a golden ticket that grants access to a magic chocolate factory, I guess you either submit such a ticket or argue. Perhaps you need to ask for clarification about what calculation the reviewer wants performed, as many calculations can legitimately be considered $R^2$; just look at what UCLA writes about $R^2$ for a logistic regression.
There is an argument for doing such a calculation of $\left[\operatorname{corr}\left(y, \hat y\right)\right]^2$. This is, after all, one of several equivalent calculations of $R^2$ in the familiar OLS setting (in-sample, with an intercept).
The trouble with such a calculation is that it can miss that predictions are terrible. For instance, $y = (1, 2, 3)$ and $\hat y = (-11, -21, -31)$ have a perfect $\left[\operatorname{corr}\left(y, \hat y\right)\right]^2 = 1$, yet the predictions are terrible. They would never happen in an in-sample OLS linear regression with an intercept, but you are not in such a situation.
Another $R^2$ calculation that is equivalent to $\left[\operatorname{corr}\left(y, \hat y\right)\right]^2$ in the OLS setting is $
R^2=1-\left(\dfrac{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\hat y_i
\right)^2
}{
\overset{N}{\underset{i=1}{\sum}}\left(
y_i-\bar y
\right)^2
}\right)
$. If you apply this to $y = (1, 2, 3)$ and $\hat y = (-11, -21, -31)$, you will get a value less than zero, correctly flagging the poor fit.
This also has an interpretation as being a comparison to a baseline or benchmark model, one that always predicts the conditional mean to be the marginal mean. In the absence of any covariate information, what better prediction for the conditional mean than the marginal mean? If you cannot beat a benchmark or competitor, there is a strong argument not to use such predictions that are outperformed by other predictions. This interpretation holds, regardless of estimation technique, so your lack of maximum likelihood estimation is not a problem.
There are ways to extend such a calculation to other notions of performance besides square loss. I discuss here how to generalize to quantile regression loss. I discuss here how to generalize to classification accuracy. In the absence of a compelling reason to use a measure of performance other than square loss (you may have one when you use weights), I see it as perfectly reasonable to use such a calculation. If you want to penalize overfitting, perhaps you can do an out-of-sample calculation, which I discuss here with a reference to the literature that you can cite.
I have confidence in your ability to paraphrase what I have written here to make an argument for why you have calculated $R^2$ the way you choose to calculate.
